# Does it matter which way Torbjörn's turret faces?

Tags: overwatch

Seeing how there is no rotate function when placing a turret, does it matter at all which way Torbjörn's turret faces when planting it?  Are there any advantages, like perhaps a faster turn speed or detection speed in specific directions? Or does it not matter which way it faces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will have to say it does matter which direction the Turret is facing. 
The turret will [default](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/torbjorn.html) to the position it was facing when first created, so there will be a slight delay between a forward facing turret and a backwards facing turret when an enemy is in LOS.

Although given discussions on [rebrn](http://rebrn.com/re/typical-torbjrn-potg-2612870/), it seams the rotation speed is **near** instantaneous, but not 0, so it is a matter of milliseconds.

For Pro players, it probably matters, but for the casual bunch it shouldn't.

EDIT: 
As per further request, and of course my bad for not adding this, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZJyMo3YKA) is how fast the turret rotates 180' It clearly takes some time and is much better to have the turret facing the enemies, than having it turn away after a clutch.

Judging by the video and Youtube's .25 play speed. It took a second for the turret to rotate 180'(MAYBE 1.25 seconds).

Comment: Just because the client _shows_ the turret turning doesn't mean there is actually a turn wait-time on the server.  I created  the bounty hoping someone would do some **SCIENCE™** to figure that out.  Both answers are currently just speculation.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My bad, refer to my edited answer.

Comment: That video is definitely not current, my experience is that the turret turns **way** faster than that.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft i would agree, however there is a turnspeed, you can sneak from behind and not get shot the moment you round a corner.

Comment: I feel like the only way to satisfy the bounty is with a frame by frame comparison video showing what the small amount of actual time is, mixed with server recognition of someone being hit. Things outside of my technical ability :)

Comment: @Mayshar It most likely is, however my specs are too low for me to be able to run the game and recording software and get proper data out. Other than that it's not too hard to stretch a 5s video in windows movie maker, and analyse that

Answer (score 15):

Torbjorn's turret instantly detects enemies and if there's a turn speed, it hasn't been noticeable to me. Therefore, you shouldn't need to worry about which way the turret is facing when placing it.

Comment: There is a turn speed, but it's a lot faster than TF2s.

Comment: I have to imagine there is technically a turn/aim speed, but in practice, it doesnt appear to matter in the game. Its most likely milliseconds if anything.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, there are advantages to certain orientations of the turret during placement, although they are fairly minor.** The specifics of this depend on what you're trying to accomplish with your turret. There are two main approaches to this that I've seen.

**Out in the open**: The turret is placed near an objective or chokepoint so that it has a large field of view to engage enemies. This also means that it will be in plain sight, so it's up to your team to keep the enemy focused on them rather than your turret. *In this scenario, there's a small benefit to pointing the turret toward the locations that enemies are most likely to appear since it negates the brief (but not entirely negligible) rotation speed that occurs before it can begin firing at the enemy*. [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264602/does-it-matter-which-way-torbj%C3%B6rns-turret-faces/269229#269229) does a great job of examining the rotation speed of the turret, so I won't go into that any further.

**Tucked away**: The turret is placed somewhere that isn't immediately obvious, such as in a side room, with the intent of surprising the enemy. One tactic involves [placing the turret on a health pack](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4mgkuh/torbjorn_players_health_packs_will_heal_your/), which will not only heal the turret if it takes damage, but also increase the likelihood of finishing off an enemy that was already low on health and in need of the boost. Since the turret projects a laser that is visible to enemy attackers, pointing the turret toward a location that enemies are likely to come from can give away its position. This can allow enemy heroes to avoid the trap or destroy the turret before it can fire at them (particularly in the case of heroes such as Junkrat or Pharah who are capable of splash damage). *In this scenario, it is more advantageous to point the turret into a nearby wall so that the laser will not be noticed by the enemy until it is able to fire at them.*

In either of these two cases, I would consider these advantages to be fairly minor, but they can make a difference if you're trying to optimize your placement. I hope that helps!

Comment: _"This answer does a great job of examining the rotation speed of the turret, so I won't go into that any further"_ - That's the entire question... The rest of this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I disagree. The question asked whether there are advantages to which way the turret is facing, with rotation speed being given as one possibility. It wasn't worded as "how does rotation speed affect turret placement". My answer provides a different possible consideration that wasn't mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score -3):

I found this on a [Torbjorn play guide](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/torbjorn.html) that seems relevant:

> When putting a turret down, the turret will face the same direction that Torbjorn was facing when he puts it down.  This is important to know because the turret will always default to that direction when not firing at enemies and it will always take slightly longer for the turret to turn around and start firing at targets behind the turret.  So always face the direction where you think the turret will be firing at more often for a faster firing response time.

This implies that the turret will shoot behind, but when not actively shhoting will default back to the direction it was built in. Therefore, building facing towards a choke-point or known approach would be slightly beneficial as it will need to turn less before shooting.