# Does Torbjorn's turret have a range?

Tags: overwatch

As far as I've seen, it seems like [Torbjorn's turret doesn't need to placed in a specific direction like TF2 and Dirty Bomb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264602/does-it-matter-which-way-torbj%C3%B6rns-turret-faces), so that's not an issue.

What I'd like to know is if it has a cutoff range, or does all it need is line of sight?

Meaning, could I place it on a high position that's far up, such as on Hollywood 1st obj elevator, and still have it shoot players that are coming out from under tunnel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has a radius of 40 meters according to [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Build_Turret).

Roadhog's Chain Hook has a range of 21 meters, for comparison.